# How to connect C++ system calls to freertos

Tags: c++, arm, microcontroller, freertos, bare-metal

I want to write a multi-threading program for microcontroller with free-rtos. but I don't want to use non-standard free-rtos functions, instead, I want to use the native c++  library to run parallel and async tasks. but I don't know how to write an adapter for connecting c++ system calls for thread creation to free-rtos functions.

mcu: arm cortex m4 stm32f407

c++ version: 17

Comment: A third option would be to use the standard C++ thread library.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think what you suggest is precise what the OP wants to do. The challenge is likely to be that C++ standard library implementations rely on POSIX threads, but RTOSs usually have a native thread API that is not POSIX

Comment: @marko I may have misunderstand what OP wants. There should not be any need to write an adapter. The standard library should contain all abstractions needed and it's free to use pthreads or whatever is available in the native API.

Comment: @marko my project is on microcontroller and doesn't have any operating system so libraries like std thread or pthread WILL NOT WORK without OS as you said right? so I added the free-rtos to my project to use multithreading but some libraries use the native c++ thread or pthread library and they wont work with the free-rtos functions. so I need to connect the std thread library to the free-rtos functions somehow. right? I just want to know how I can do this

Comment: @MahyarShokraeian What you want is impossible! Although, you can write a wrapper on FreeRTOS as its upper layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that FreeRTOS has a [POSIX threads adaptor](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_POSIX/index.html) layer.  It's a subset, but probably enough to build a `thread`, `mutex`, and `future`  from either GNU `libstdc++` or clang `libc++` against. You will almost certainly need a working `std::atomic` implementation.

There's a lot of grot in POSIX threads that resulted from its retro-fit to various UNIX-alike operating systems, and it's highly likely you won't want the bits not supported.  For good reason, it's not the default threading API of many RTOSs.

Comment: In his question, where did he say about the POSIX adapter? According to his question, it seems that he wants a special C++ library `std :: thread` that works with FreeRTOS. In addition to the fact that POSIX is a `C` API set, there are many differences between `std::thread` and POSIX in their APIs. Anyway, it's wonderful that he has confirmed this answer!

Answer (score 2):

The standard defines an interface, it specifies the syntax and may define some requirements on their performance, but it is not going to define how to implement the task scheduler, this is compiler's duty.

Actually, that is what `std::thread` often is, a wrapper which uses threads from the OS (or lower layers) and relies on them. If you  have a C++11 compliant compiler to include `std::thread`, obviously you don't have to do anything. Otherwise, you do have to code your own abstraction layer or use a wrapper coded by anyone else, there are many ideas on the internet, i.e.: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1278513/Cplusplus11-FreeRTOS-GCC